# Doubt regarding some overlooked steps when arriving at torque, in terms of Newtonian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, vectors, torque

The treatment of torque in most undergraduate introductory mechanics textbooks or pre-college textbooks assumes many things and doesn't explicitly state its assumptions. Torque is one such example. I have a somewhat concrete approach towards torque, but there are some steps that I don't agree with, in my route:

we know that $ \vec v = \vec \omega \times \vec r$ (from circular motion)

$\frac{d \vec v}{dt} = \frac{d \vec \omega}{dt} \times \vec r + \vec \omega \times \frac{d 
\vec r}{dt} $ (using product rule)

$\vec a = \frac{d \vec \omega}{dt} \times \vec r + \vec \omega \times (\vec \omega \times \vec r) $ (from the first equation)

we use the BAC-CAB identity to find

$ \vec \omega \times (\vec \omega \times \vec r)  = \vec \omega(\vec \omega \cdot \vec r)-\vec r(\vec \omega \cdot \vec \omega)$

In most calculations, this term
$ \vec \omega \cdot \vec r$
gets cancelled because it is considered to be zero (in Resnick for example this isn't treated at all, and in kleppner it is assumed to be perpendicular) and from this we get to torque by taking $\vec r \times F $ and so on.

But if we assume it is a system of particles that is doing a rotation around a specified axis, we know that not all particles' $\vec r$ will be perpendicular to the $\vec \omega$ and hence the term doesn't necessarily cancel. Can someone explain the workaround for this, or the problems with my approach?

Comment: You have written yourself after the your very first equation *from circular motion* with $\vec r$ being from an origin, not any fixed axis.

Comment: Dear @farcher , I have mentioned $ \vec v = \vec \omega \times \vec r$ because it works even when the axis is arbitrary. I am saying circular motion because the projection or $ \vec r$ onto the axis perpendicular to $ \vec \omega $ gives me a circular motion which obeys the rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's draw a diagram:

[image: Angular velocity]

We can choose any origin for the position vector $\mathbf r$, and we would normally choose the origin to make $\mathbf r$ perpendicular to the axis. But you are interested in the general case so that's what I've drawn.

Now, we can write the position vector as the sum of two vectors parallel to an perpendicular to the axis:

$$ \mathbf r = \mathbf r_x + \mathbf r_z $$

And we can substitute this into the expression:

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega}(\boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \mathbf r)-\mathbf r(\boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega}) $$

to get:

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega}|\omega|~|r_z| - \mathbf r_x |\omega|^2 - \mathbf r_z |\omega|^2 $$

and's just $-\mathbf r_x \omega^2$ i.e. the same result as if we took the position vector perpendicular to the axis. So it doesn't matter what origin we have for the position vector we're always going to end up with the centripetal component of the acceleration.